# gvim how to change entire background color

Tags: colors, gvim, color-theme

Okay so im my .vimrc file, I did type

```
hi Normal guibg=#000000
```

changing the background color to black, however, this only changes the background color of the lines where I have typed out text. If the lines are empty and there is no line number for it, then the background color is still grey (the default background color for the color scheme which I am using, which is called 'slate'). How do I change the entire background color to blank, including the lines which I have not typed anything on?

Also, secondary question, what's the difference between guibg and guifg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the exact same problem with the `jellybeans` theme. It took me a while and I came back here to answer your question for future reference.
`hi Normal` will only change the colors of the text area, to change the background of the empty text area you use `hi NonText guibg=#color ctermbg=#color`.
For instance, I wanted to get rid of the background color since I'm using a semi-transparent background terminal so I used `hi NonText ctermbg=NONE` and that solved it.